# Rotate an axis aligned rectangle by a 90 degrees

Tags: c++, rotation, 2d, sfml

I have rectangle object (`sf::IntRect`) , with attributes: left, top, width and height on a 2D plane. I want to rotate it by a multiple of 90 degrees (that is 90, 180 or 270), around point (0,0). Thus I am writing a function like this:

```
void rotateRect(sf::IntRect& rect, int rot)
{
    //code I need
}
```

the rotation is either 0 (0), 1 (90), 2 (180) or 3 (270).

How can I achieve this as simply as possible.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am not familiar with SFML. It probably has functions to compute the transform matrices for the above rotations. If not, they are very simple. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix.

Comment: Look at `sf::Transform`. But are you sure you want to use **Int**Rect?

Comment: I probably didn't express my question clearly enough. The problem is not rotating the points, I've done that before using a rotation matrix. I just cant wrap my head around redefining the top left hand corner simply. Im sure there is a simple equation I can use, but I cant find it. @Hiura yes I'm just trying out something, and it's not very SFML orientated

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic solution using `sf::Tranform` on `sf::FloatRect`:

```
constexpr auto rotationAngle(int rot) { return rot * 90.f; }

void rotateRect(sf::IntRect& rect, int rot)
{
    auto deg = rotationAngle(rot);
    auto transform = sf::Transform();
    transform.rotate(deg);

    // Would be better if rect was a FloatRect...
    auto rectf = sf::FloatRect(rect);
    rectf = transform.transformRect(rectf);
    rect = static_cast<sf::IntRect>(rectf);
}
```

However, I personally would slightly change the signature of your function to use float rects and a more compact notation:

```
sf::FloatRect rotateRect(sf::FloatRect const& rect, int rot)
{
    return sf::Transform().rotate(rotationAngle(rot)).transformRect(rect);
}
```

And below a full example showing how it behaves.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

constexpr auto rotationAngle(int rot) { return rot * 90.f; }

sf::FloatRect rotateRect(sf::FloatRect const& rect, int rot)
{
    return sf::Transform().rotate(rotationAngle(rot)).transformRect(rect);
}

void updateShape(sf::RectangleShape& shape, sf::FloatRect const& rect)
{
    shape.setPosition(rect.left, rect.top);
    shape.setSize({ static_cast<float>(rect.width), static_cast<float>(rect.height) });
}

int main(int, char const**)
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "rotate");

    auto rect = sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
    auto shape = sf::RectangleShape();
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    updateShape(shape, rect);

    auto view = window.getView();
    view.move({ -250, -250 });
    window.setView(view);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R)
            {
                rect = rotateRect(rect, 1);
                updateShape(shape, rect);
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::N)
            {
                rect = sf::FloatRect(50, 50, 100, 50);
                updateShape(shape, rect);
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::M)
            {
                rect = sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
                updateShape(shape, rect);
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

NB: I used a few trick from C++14 but I'm sure you can convert that code to C++11/C++98 if you need to.